# Django annotate on BooleanField

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    is_successful = models.BooleanField()
```

I would like to get all `foo` objects with an annotation if all of the `bar` objects associated with `foo` object have `is_successful` as `True`

So far my queryset is:

```
foos = Foo.objects.all().annotate(all_successful=Min('bar__is_successful'))
```

The idea for the `all_successful` annotation is that if the minimum value of all `is_successful` rows is 1, then all of them must be `True` (assuming `0` is `False` and `1` is `True`). So knowing that I can use the queryset like so:

```
foo = foos[0]

if foo.all_successful == 1:
    print 'All bars are successful'
else:
    print 'Not all bars are successful'
```

This works great in sqlite however it fails in PostgreSQL because PostgreSQL can't execute `MIN` aggregate on a boolean column. I guess this works in sqlite because sqlite treats bools as integers hence it can execute the aggregate.

My question is how can I make this queryset work in PostgreSQL without converting my `is_successful` field to an `IntegerField`?

Thanx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I ran up against this recently.  Django v1.8 now has built in support for case/when, so you can use the ORM instead of hacking around with custom SQL.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case

```
Foo.objects.annotate(
    all_successful=Case(
        When(bar__is_successful=False, then=False),
        When(bar__is_successful=True, then=True),
        default=False,
        output_field=BooleanField()
    ))
```

I haven't tried this out, but something similar worked for me on a recent project.

Comment: this is the preferable approach now, good point! thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Your syntax is easier to follow than the actual documentation, thanks! Missing a final `)` in code block. Also, please add a final kwarg `output_field=BooleanField()` to the `Case()` call.

Comment: Changes made.  :)

Answer (score 3):

**FOR DJANGO <= 1.7:** to get an `annotation` I think you can *simply* use [Extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

```
foos = Foo.objects.extra(select={'all_successful': 'CASE WHEN COUNT(b.foo) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM yourapp_bar as b WHERE b.is_successful = false and b.foo = yourapp_foo.id' })
```

if your system is running **Django 1.8+** please follow Dav3xor [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32933336/582906).

Comment: This is brilliant. I was looking for a good way to use a SQL "CASE WHEN" in Django, and this nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

being inspired by https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/ I suggest to use a custom manager for Bar class instead of annotation

```
class BarManager(models.Manager):
    def get_all_successful_foos_ids(self):
        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
            SELECT foo, COUNT(*)
            FROM yourapp_bar
            GROUP BY 1
            WHERE is_successful = true""")  # <-- you have to write the correct table name here
        result_list = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            if row[1] > 0:
                result_list.append(row[0])
        return result_list

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    is_successful = models.BooleanField()
    objects = BarManager()  # here I'm changing the default manager
```

then, in your code:

```
foos = foo.objects.filter(id__in=Bar.objects.get_all_successful_foos_ids())
```

Comment: Thanx for the idea but that is not what I am looking for because your suggestions just filters the queryset whereas I am looking how to annotate my foo model.

Comment: I wrote another answer, with a simpler approach that should give you the expected annotation (I had no time to test it but it should put you on the right direction, I hope)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will return multiple results (non-distinct), and if you use distinct, not all conditions will be checked.

I use this instead:

```py
Foo.objects.annotate(
    all_bar=Count('bar'),
    all_successful=Count('bar__is_successful'),
)
```

and then you only have to compare counts:

```py
if obj.all_successful == obj.all_bar:
    print(obj, 'is fully successful')
```