# Django annotate on boolean Field

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

```py
class Forecast(Model):
    id = UUID()
    type = StringField()
    approved = BooleanField()
```

I want to group on the field `type` by applying 'logical and' on approved field. Suppose the annotated field is `all_approved`. `all_approved` should be True if all the items with that type is True, and false if atleast one is False.

So finally in my queryset i want to have two fields `type`, `all_approved`.

How can i achieve this?

I tried something based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32933336/3701807), but couldn't get anything.

**EDIT:**

when i tried whats given in that answer, its not doing 'logical and'. Instead for each `type` it just give two items, one with `all_approved` as True, another with `all_approved` as False. I want a single item for each `type`.

Also i don't understand why that answer should work. Where is it specified if while grouping it should do 'logical and' or 'logical or'.

Comment: please, show what you try and what was wrong based on your data, because in the answer you linked there is a good example.

Comment: or read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775011/how-to-annotate-count-with-a-condition-in-a-django-queryset

Comment: @BearBrown edited the answer

Comment: In the article you linked they are using Count for aggregation. But i cant find any Django database function with act on Boolean Field. eg I tried Min(), but it just fails.

Comment: i added answer where i try to say what i mean when put the link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

other solution: you can try compare all `approved` with `approved=True`

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, BooleanField

Forecast.objects.values(
    'type'
).annotate(
    cnt_app=Count(Case(When(approved=True, then=1)))
).annotate(
    all_approved=Case(
        When(cnt_app=Count('approved'), then=True),
        default=False,
        output_field=BooleanField()
   )
).values('type', 'all_approved')
```

where

`Count(Case(When(approved=True, then=1)))` gives us count of the approved with status True for the type,

`Count('approved')` gives us total count of the all for the type,

and if the values is equal then all_approved is True other way False

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to flip `all_approved` to `False` for types that have at least one `False` value:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField
from django.db.models.expressions import Case, When

(Forecast.objects
    .annotate(all_approved=Case(
        When(type__in=Forecast.objects.filter(approved=False).values('type'), 
             then=False),
        default=True,
        output_field=BooleanField()
    ))
    .values('type', 'all_approved')
    .distinct()
)
```

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373569/django-annotate-on-booleanfield/32933336#32933336) you've linked is a bit different because it relates to a one-to-many relationship between two models that are joined automatically by Django.

Here you have just one model, which you'd have to join with itself to use the same solution. Since Django only supports joins defined by relationships, you need the subquery as a workaround.

Comment: type is a string field. what i want is annotation on approved. This wont work.

Comment: `So finally in my queryset i want to have two fields type, all_approved.`

Comment: Updated answer to give the requested two columns.